# Taking an integral over a triangle?

Tags: integration, notation

I'm reading through the MIT primes application problems and one of the problems is:
[image]

And I am not familiar with the notation of taking a single integral over a triangle. Is $f$ supposed to be a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and the integral is actually a double integral? I feel like the problem wouldn't be valid if this were the case, so can someone explain to me what this notation is?

Comment: Is there any context? I think you are right. It should be a double integral and $f=f(x,y)$.

Comment: The image displayed is the only context

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't a paraboloid disprove this if it were in fact a question of double integration?

Comment: It says in "any" rectangle though.